# Get latest rows in PostgresSQL table ordered by Date: Index or Sort table?

Tags: postgresql

I had a hard time titling this question but I hope its appropriate.

I have a table of transactions, and each transaction has a Date column (of type Date).

I want to run a query that gets the latest 100 transactions by date (simple enough with an ORDERBY query).

My question is, in order to make this an extremely cheap operation, would it make sense to sort my entire table so that I just need to select the top 100 rows every time, or do i simply create an index on the date column? Not sure if first option is even possible and or/good sql db practice.

Comment: Is the Date coumn indexed ?

Comment: no not yet ....

Comment: Adding an index on the Date column should be enough

Comment: *Would it make sense to sort my entire table*? **No**. Quite simply without `order by` on the query you will not/can not get a deterministic order in the result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would add an index on the column with the date and query:

```
SELECT * FROM tab
ORDER BY datecol DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

The problem with your other idea is that there is no well-defined order in a table. Every `UPDATE` changes this "order", and even if you don't modify anything, a sequential scan need not start at the beginning of the table.

Comment: when i define the index, is there an ordering paramater?

Comment: The index can be imagined as a sorted list of pointers to the table rows. The ordering is that defined by `<` and `>`. What parameters do you have in mind?

Comment: just wondering when i create the index do i set ASC or DESC. I created it  without specifying and the query appears to be fast enough for my needs. Thank you

Comment: Indexes can be read in both directions with the same speed, so that does not matter for the speed of the query.